# Is there a way to output text to the R console in color

Tags: r, colors, console, output-formatting

I am writing a script and I want to output text messages to the console with different colors depending on conditions. For example: RED for errors and BLUE for warnings, etc.

I am using RStudio.

Comment: I'm not sure about RStudio, but this is possible in the RJava client of Eclipse StatET.

Comment: It might be best to post this to the RStudio forums. (My guess is that it's not possible without serious hacking.)

Comment: I'm addicted to library(colorout).  But it doesn't work with RStudio :-(

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am asking in the R Studio forums now. I tried with some of the packages mentioned without success.

Comment: seems its on the way? https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2574

Comment: There's a solution to this using base R [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57031762/4549096).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option could be using the [`insight`](https://github.com/easystats/insight) package with the [`print_color`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/insight/html/print_color.html) function. You could also make the text **bold** or *italic*. Here is some reproducible code:

```
library(insight)
print_color("ERROR", "red")
print_color("WARNINGS", "blue")
```

Output RStudio:

[image]

Answer (score 62):

Check out the new [`crayon` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/crayon/index.html):

```
library(crayon)
cat(blue("Hello", "world!\n"))
```

More info on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/gaborcsardi/crayon).

Works in RStudio 1.2.360+

Comment: I have already searched it, and also found in SO questions, but it don't work. it just print the string without color specified in R console.

Comment: @itfeature.com: Which particular R console are you using?

Comment: It didn't work for me and I'm using R Studio Version 0.99.892 – © 2009-2016 RStudio, Inc.

Comment: @Jazzmine: Color support on the console is yet to be added to RStudio. See e.g. https://github.com/hadley/tibble/issues/30.

Comment: I've installed the crayon package from Github repository but in my case `cat(blue("Hello", "world!\n"))` still returns black text color :(

Comment: @Florent: In the terminal, or in RStudio?

Comment: @krlmlr It is in RStudio

Comment: @Florent, the crayon package contains a has_color() function that I noticed was basically always returning false on Windows. However, I downloaded the ConEmu terminal emulator and it does work there. I haven't played around with ComEmu's features but it looks like a nice emulator that, unlike Cygwin, easily runs R.

Comment: Works fine for me (Linux Mint 18.2, R 3.4.3, Crayon 1.3.4, RStudio 1.2.360).

Comment: It works for me as well, Windows 10, R-3.4.4, RStudio 1.1.383

Comment: It works for me Windows 10, R 3.6.1, RStudio 1.2.1335. It did not work until after I upgraded R above 3.3.1.

Comment: This works on xfce4-terminal on ArchLinux and on Jupyter Notebook too.

Comment: Works for me using R 4.0.4 and R-studio 1.4.1106, in 20220110.

Answer (score 3):

The [**xterm256** package](http://romainfrancois.blog.free.fr/index.php?post/2009/04/18/Colorful-terminal%3A-the-R-package-%22xterm256%22) by Romain Francoise allows this sort of thing in general on any console that understands xterm256 interrupts.

Comment: This looks promising but doesn't work in R Studio. Too bad for me. Thanks for the tip

Comment: is there any further update on this? Or we still do not have any R package that outputs coloured text on Rstudio console or alternatively on the plot  or view pane of Rstudio.

Comment: Crayon works in RStudio now for me (Linux Mint 18.2, R 3.4.3, Crayon 1.3.4, RStudio 1.2.360).

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there IS a way without using R packages (Crayon and cli):

Use **cat**, **paste0** and some ANSI hell to do it:

```
txt<-"rainbow"
for(col in 29:47){ cat(paste0("\033[0;", col, "m",txt,"\033[0m","\n"))}
```

You will need to do a bigger function, since cat is not very flexible, but this works well.

Obs: This solution was observed by a colleague, which is a perl stan.

Answer (score 1):

On either Linux or Mac, you could try https://github.com/jalvesaq/colorout
It doesn't work on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game but building on @Pedro_S's answer here's an example of how could write functions to use ANSI colours to print coloured text based on plain text input of colours (`"red"`, `"green"`, etc.):

```
#' Convert plain text colour to ANSI code
#'
#' @param colour colour in plain text ("red", "green", etc.) to convert to ANSI
#'
#' @return string representing provided colour as ANSI encoding
#'
#' @examples
#' colour_to_ansi("red") # gives: "\033[31m"
colour_to_ansi <- function(colour) {
  # Note ANSI colour codes
  colour_codes <- list(
    "black" = 30,
    "red" = 31,
    "green" = 32,
    "yellow" = 33,
    "blue" = 34,
    "magenta" = 35,
    "cyan" = 36,
    "white" = 37
  )

  # Check colour provided in codes above
  if (colour %in% names(colour_codes) == FALSE) {
    stop(
      paste0(
        "Colour provided (", colour, ") can't be converted to ANSI. ",
        "Must be one of: \n", paste(names(colour_codes), collapse = ",")
      )
    )
  }

  # Create ANSI version of colour
  ansi_colour <- paste0("\033[", colour_codes[[colour]], "m")

  return(ansi_colour)
}

#' Print (cat) progress text as coloured text
#'
#' @param text string to print using cat()
#' @param colour plain text colour ("red", "green", etc.). Defaults to "green"
#'
#' @examples
#' coloured_print("This is a test", colour = "blue")
coloured_print <- function(text, colour = "green") {
  cat(colour_to_ansi(colour), text, "\033[0m\n")
}
```