# R - How to output a partially colored string in R?

Tags: r

I want to output a partially colored string. e.g. something like:

> print(paste("This is how", style("Red","red", "bold"), "looks."))

[1] "This is how **Red** looks."

The string **Red** should be colored in red.

Any help will be much appreciated!!

Comment: You generally just get one color printed to the console, looks like there is an option for this though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802806/is-there-a-way-to-output-some-text-to-the-r-console-in-colors?rq=1 using `xterm256` package

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "output." Agstudy shows how to plot it;  if you want a text document, you're best off learning to generate LaTex or HTML code in R.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for your time.
@ScottChamberlain : I am not sure why is it so difficult.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft : I meant output on screen. Even an html file output would be great.

Comment: If you are using text in a R markdown document you could use `This is how <font color="red">Red</font> looks`. I tried `xterm256` - it does work in the R terminal, but didn't work in RStudio.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802806/is-there-a-way-to-output-text-to-the-r-console-in-color

Answer (score 1):

You can hack it using `text`:

```
plot(1:10,1:10,type='n',frame.plot=F,axes=F,xlab="",ylab="")
text(5,1,"This is how")
text(5.8,1,"Red",col='red',font=2)
text(6.3,1,"looks.")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the `crayon` package can help you:

```
library(crayon)
cat("This is how", red("Red"), "looks.\n")
```

Output:

[image]

If you want more features, perhaps the [xterm256 package](http://romainfrancois.blog.free.fr/index.php?post/2009/04/18/Colorful-terminal%3A-the-R-package-%22xterm256%22) will be helpful.