# How to change the colour of the printed output in base R?

Tags: r

I would like to change the colour of some output printed in R without importing external libraries. How can I do this?

I already know

```
print('this is black')
```

and

```
message('this is red')
```

But how can I do other colours? Green or blue, for example

#### Note

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802806/is-there-a-way-to-output-text-to-the-r-console-in-color/29780221) except I am limited to using base R (no packages)

Comment: This depends on the terminal. For example, in R with a basic terminal on many systems there are no colors at all. What system and what R distribution (e.g. rstudio) are you using?

Comment: A work around could be to use plot `plot(0:1,0:1, type = 'n', axes = FALSE, ann = FALSE); text(0.5,0.5, 'test', col = 'orange')`

Comment: It’s not for me but for users of a script I’m working on. They’ll be using the most recent version of rstudio. I just need it to stand out more than black but not resemble an error (red)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try use this:

```
txt<-"test"
for(col in 29:47){ cat(paste0("\033[0;", col, "m",txt,"\033[0m","\n"))}
```

or if you want other function interesting i find this

https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/blob/717b02164def5c1f027d3a20b889dae35428b6d7/R/colour-text.r

Comment: This is great. Can you explain how it works, or more specifically how I can get any particular colour? Is it using hex or something? (I've worked out something like `cat("\033[0;32mtest\033[0m\n")` gives green, but I still don't know how it does that

Comment: You can find a good explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842424/list-of-ansi-color-escape-sequences

Comment: Thanks for the link! I read it, plus some googling. Is it true to say you cannot produce all of the 16,777,216 colours that RGB can create? I.e. only [these](https://superuser.com/questions/270214/how-can-i-change-the-colors-of-my-xterm-using-ansi-escape-sequences) ones? Is there a way to get the other colours? E.g. `#FF6600`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know if there are other ways to get other colors. If you find other methods, write them here so I can learn them too.