# Is there an R function for applying color to digits in a vector?

Tags: r, vector

I'm generating 8 individual vectors of 18 random numbers, and I want to color-code all the numbers under 11 red and everything else can stay black.

`trial1 <- sample(0:99, 18, repeat = TRUE)` performed 8 times, changing the trial number each time.

```
 if (trial1<=11) {
     print(col ="red")
 } else {
     print(col = "black")
```

but this throws an error message and I don't know where I messed up. I'm trying to display all 18 numbers as either red or black. Is this possible, and how do I do it?

Comment: Are you talking about printing to your console, or somewhere else (e.g., in an Rmarkdown document). If you're talking about printing in your R console, then the `crayon` package has you covered, [see this dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10802806/903061).

Comment: The error is because `print` needs an argument to print that is either the first unnamed argument or named `x`. `print(col = "black")` doesn't tell it what to print. (And also, there is no `col` argument, but `print` is willing to let that slide and ignore it, as long as you give it something to print...). You can always check the help page `?print` to see what arguments a function takes.

Answer (score 0):

As was said in the comments, you can't do `print(col = ...)`. However, you can store it in a vector:

```
> trial1 <- sample(0:99, 18)

> col1 <- ifelse(trial1 <= 11, "red", "black")

> trial1
 [1] 41 77 81 87 84  3 32 14 86 20 25 37 67 45 17 98 31 53

> col1
 [1] "black" "black" "black" "black" "black" "red"   "black" "black" "black" "black" "black" "black"
[13] "black" "black" "black" "black" "black" "black"
```

Also, I don't know what you mean with `repeat  = TRUE`. Maybe you mean `replace = TRUE`.

Comment: You can also do it in a data frame, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [‘crayon’ package](https://github.com/r-lib/crayon) in combination with R’s `ifelse`:

```r
trial1 = sample(0 : 99, 18L, replace = TRUE)

cat(toString(ifelse(trial1 <= 11, crayon::red(trial1), trial1)), '\n')
```

‘crayon’ itself does no printing, it generates [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) that many terminals interpret as colour commands. When passed to `cat`, this generates colourful output (if the terminal supports it).

Note that you need a command such as `cat`, `message` or `writeLines` here — `print` doesn’t work. The reason is that, contrary to what its name suggests, the `print` function doesn’t actually print proper output. Instead, it creates (and prints) a *debug representation* of R objects. That’s why it always prints indices on the left next to vectors, and why it prints strings surrounded by `"…"`.

If you want to produce output in a script, `print` is almost *always* the wrong choice. Instead, you’d use one of the functions mentioned above.